# Identifying if 'null' was deliberately set on the input JSON

Tags: java, json, rest, api, jersey

We are creating a REST API for managing a resource. We are using `Jersey` framework.

Following is the structure of the `JSON`

```
cable {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Cable 1",
  "description": "Test Cable",
  "Site": 4
}
```

The JSON should map to the below class.

```
public class CableDTO {

  private Long id;

  private String name;

  private String description;

  //private SiteDTO site;
  private Long siteID;

  .
  .
  .

  // Getters ans Setters

}
```

Site is actually a reference object. The input and output JSON, requires the `CableDTO` to contain **Site id** instead of the entire `Site` object. We have **assemblers** which convert the DTO's to Domain objects and vice-versa.

The sample assembler code is as below:

```
public class CableAssembler {

  //some code

  public void fillDomain(Cable cable, CableDto dto){
    if(dto.getId() != null) cable.setID(dto.getId());
    if(dto.getSiteID() != null) cable.setSiteId(dto.getSiteId())

    //some more code below
  }

}
```

This assembler works well when a brand new **POST HTTP** method is called. If the `SiteID` is not set in the input json, the site is set to null and all is hunky dory. However, on a **PUT HTTP** call, if the `SiteID` is not set, the existing `SiteID` is over written to `null`. This is because the same assembler is used in both PUT and POST call. The assembler checks if the siteID set in the DTO is `null`. If it is `null`, the existing `siteID` is overwritten. The problem is, I am not able to distinguish between whether the `null` value in the `SiteID` is because the value was not sent or the `SiteID` was indeed deliberately set to `null` (which is possible `{"siteID":null}` )

Any pointers on how to solve this? 
We use `Jackson` for serialization/de-serialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood right your situation, my propositions are:

- If you can, add a `boolean` field to JSON and DTO telling if the `siteID` was set and sent and check it in the assembler or other code;
- Give the `siteId` another default value, different from `null`, like `-1` or `0`, if it's possible.

Comment: Thnx @mortalis. Sometimes in the complex world of libraries, we do forget simple things. I was of the opinion that there would be some way the JSON library annotation would help and do some automagic. But the idea of setting a boolean is a simple and elegant solution. thnx.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you use your PUT request like PATCH request. To use PUT request properly you should GET cable info, change some fields and PUT back. In this case your siteId field will remain unchanged.

Comment: PUT/PATCH/POST , all go through the same assembler. The point is if somebody wants to disassociate the site from the cable, he can send a {"siteID":null} . How do I now make out that the siteID was sent or not. For e.g. of the input json now is {"description":"changed desc"}, then in both the cases I get siteID as null. In the latter case, the siteID should not be disassociated from the cable.

Comment: This is why PATCH method is preferred if you want to change only part of the entity. Your {"description":"changed desc"} in PATCH will not overwrite siteId. In the case of PUT you should specify existing siteId value (as well as other values) to not miss them: {"description":"changed desc", "siteId": "currentSiteId", ...}.